# Scrapy selectors are not grabing the full text in an element

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I have this element in the html document

```
<div class="main-l">
    <i class="icon icon-small icon-pin"></i> 65203 Wiesbaden</div>
```

trying to get the lement with `.css('.main-l::text').get()` give me only the partial text: `'\r\n    '`. This is the text before the `i` element.
How to get the full text or the text after the `i` element?

Comment: Needs to be edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get full text, you have to call `.getall()` method

```
response.css('.main-l::text').getall()
```

Proved by scrapy shell

```
In [1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [2]: %paste
html='''
<div class="main-l">
    <i class="icon icon-small icon-pin"></i> 65203 Wiesbaden</div>
'''

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: response = Selector(text=html)

In [4]: 
   ...: ' '.join(response.css('.main-l::text').getall()).strip()
Out[4]: '65203 Wiesbaden'
```